# Django: query to iterate through a column values and search match in another table

Tags: mysql, django

I have this 2 tables in my DB :

[image]

[image]

I would like a query to iterate through **"company_members-id"** and if there is a match in the **"table_contacts" id column**, return the line as a result

I need to use the result in my HTML template to populate a selectbox with something like this  :

HTML template :

```
<select id="members_in_companies">
        {% for option in rendered_result %}
            <option value="{{ option.id}} "> {{ option.first_name}} + " " + {{ option.last_name}} </option>
        {% endfor %}

    </select>
```

For example :
iterate through the "Nike" company would populate the selectbox with 2 and 4 as selectbox value and " Ellon Musk" and "Willy Wonka".

[image]

Comment: If the current database structure is fixed, there is no simple query that can achieve this I suppose. You just have to join `company_members_ids` with ';' delimiter and use `pk__in` for querying `table_contacts`. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/)
But if you can change the database structure, try and use one-to-many relationship for this purpose. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

Comment: Unfortunately the DB structure is fixed. Can you fill me in with to the  "join company_members_ids with ';' delimiter and use __in__ query " solution ? THanks

Comment: The fact that the structure is fixed is very worrying. It does not satisfy first normal form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form which means that the database is hard to update, keep in sync, and guarantee referential integrity.

Comment: @Nico44044 The best way is for you to read the links I provided above, try some code. and include them in the question. Then if it did not work, we can provide further help. And if it worked you can post your own answer!

Comment: The only right way to fix this is *not* using a separated list of primary keys, since it makes filtering hard, and making queries - as you found out - a lot harder as well.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Good point. In case OP did use the appropriate structure, they could have used a standard query and they didn't have to come here in the first place

Comment: I know it's not the good way to do this but i'm searching for a workaround. It makes it harder but certainly not impossible that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: @Nico44044: no, but it almost definitely pays of to introduce a small data migration. Then we're done. Text processing, etc. only will slow down the database since it can not use an index, but will have to fall back on linear search.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem :  I'm with you but I can't this not one of my project so my hands are tied  and I have to find a solution as it is, doesn't matter if it slows down the process